# event bubbling in Jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, uidatepicker

I have a pop menu that contains a form with a jquery datepicker and the issue is that when I make a date selection, both the menu and the datepicker calendar closes.

I tried to use event.stopPropagation() in the Select event for the datepicker, but the I couldn't find a way to get a handle for the "event".

Also, I tried to **return false** at the end of the select event but again with no luck. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Any code will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How do you close the `datepicker`? Your code will help to answer you better.

Comment: here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/NZ4zd/1/

Comment: Here is a sample withe the jquery ui css included:http://jsfiddle.net/NZ4zd/2/

Answer (score 8):

I was facing same issue and fixed it by adding in document ready:

```
/*Stop datepicker from closing dropdown menu*/
    $("#ui-datepicker-div").click( function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

the trick is that datepicker creates a div with id ui-datepicker-div so just stop event bubbling from that container and everything will work fine.

Source: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/datepicker-propogates-click-events

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by modifying the code so that the menu ignores any clicks from the datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

i meet the same problem, at first ,i also want to stop event bubble, because, i click date picker, it doesn't work, input type is file is fired(below date picker), it solve it by setting data picker z-index to 999

code is here:
datepicker.css('z-index', 999);

it works for me